# How To change Product Detail Page Image Section Height In Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, frontend, product-images

How Can I change Product Detail Page Image Section Height.
I Need To Decrease That Section Height.

[image]

i need to fixed this left column height as right column in magento 2 can any one help me how can i change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento uses the file called `view.xml` which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme luma you should find the `view.xml` under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

In this file, you would see `<images/>` node inside the  node.

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>200</width>
                <height>248</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            ........
        </images>
    </media>
    ......
</view>
```

The dimension of the images is maintained here under the `<image/>` node.

The id attribute value of the `<image/>` node is referenced in the codebase.

For example:

```
<image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
    <width>152</width>
    <height>190</height>
</image>
```

Comment: Reference - https://store.magenest.com/blog/change-product-image-sizes/